# Limiting the resolution of vector graphics when exporting from Microsoft Word to Pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, resolution, vector-graphics

I'm having an issue with export of docx files to pdf. The docx files contain a large number of vector graphics and exporting it to pdf increases the size several times, which makes working with the files very difficult for a number of reasons.

Edit: The paragraph bellow seems to be rather my speculation, which, on further consideration, seems less likely than Microsoft Word having another bug that increases the size of vector images. Either way, any possible solutions are greatly appreciated.

Is there a way to prevent Word from exporting the images in extremely high resolution (e.g. limit the resolution of images in the exported document)?
Another possible solution might be a script that replaces all the vector graphics in the Word document with non-vector formats with a high enough resolution.

Comment: are you sure that vector graphics are the root of the problem? Generally speaking, vector images have no resolution. It's possible there is a conversion to raster at excessively high resolution, but that's outside my capabilities.

Comment: I'm quite certain. I tried converting the images to other formats before exporting and I didn't register this increase of file size, but the issue did occur when I tried exporting a docx file only containing a large vector image. I also tried using LibreOffice, which didn't produce this problem of increased file size, but has other serious issues. Is it possible that Microsoft Office really does save the picture in very high resolution instead of vector graphics?

Answer (score 0):

What tool are you using to convert your Word file to PDF?  You should be using Distiller, not the built-in functionality in Word.  Post an update and I'll research it.